# How to insert data in next empty row of a specific table in vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I currently have a formula in Columns A,B,C,D,E.
I currentltly have a table from F21:AB5000.

I need my VBA code to insert data from a userform into the next available row.

Any help please? I currently have it to input data into a new worksheet, then I use that data to specify into my original worksheet and sometimes the data format is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

*This VBA macro helps to enter new records in next empty row in the TABLE.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim rng As Range
 Set rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range

 Dim LastRow As Long

 LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", _
 After:=rng.Cells(1), _
 Lookat:=xlPart, _
 LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
 MatchCase:=False).Row

 rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
 rng.Parent.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value


End Sub
```

**N.B.**

*FIND method has been used to search the next blank row in a table for data entry.*

---

*This optional VBA code can be used to initialize User's Form controls for next entry.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim ctl As Control

 For Each ctl In Me.Controls
 If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then    
  ctl.Value = ""
 End If

Next ctl

End Sub
```

**N.B.**

- Command line can be modified for other controls like ComboBox/ListBox.

Like,

`If TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Or TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then`